# Remove regex space after submit

Tags: regex, reactjs, react-native

I'm having trouble with my regex cause I'm trying to remove the `space` after submitting my input. I have an input for credit card number where it added space after 4 digits. But when I submit the input it will save something like this `1231 2312 3123 1231` instead of this `1231231231231231` I want to remove the space after submitting my input. Below are my regex.

```
   const cardNumberInput = val => {
        const value = val.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, '').replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 ').trim();
        setCardNumber(val)
        setCardNumberDisplay(value)
    }
```

Comment: `.replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 ')` adds  spaces.

Comment: I mean the space will still be there when typing the credit card number but I want to submit the input without spaces, lets say I will save the credit card number without spaces. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: `.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, '')` removes all spaces. Remove `.replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 ')` from your code.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at

```
const value = val.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, '').replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 ').trim();
```

This - `.replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 ')` - method adds a space after each group of 4 characters.

If you do not need the spaces in your string, remove this method call:

```
const value = val.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, '').trim();
```